# Ruby on Rails: Order drop down menu contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, drop-down-menu

I'm looking for a way to order the contents of the drop down menu I have made. At the moment, the drop down menu shows each unique `client`  in the database, but in the order that they were put in the database.

```
<%= select(@projects, :client, Project.all.map {|p| [p.client]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:client]) %></br>
```

Is there a way to show them so that they are displayed in some order?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try using [`.order`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) like this?

```
Project.order("name DESC").map{|p| [p.client]}
```

Comment: That is perfect, Thank you!! I had tried this, but I was using `.order` wrong.